# using ZFS on an external USB drive for backup in Ubuntu

Tags: backup, zfs

I run **Ubuntu 12.04 precise** and would like to format, using **ZFS**, an external USB HDD to use it as a backup drive for my *home* directories.

Since it's just one drive I am not interested in self-healing since I understand this to require a RAID configuration of 2 or more disks to do it right. So being able to take snapshots of my external backup drive using ZFS native capabilities is enough, for now.

The plan is to **rsynch** my home folder onto the ZFS drive using the **--inplace** option to reduce snapshot sizes. This will hopefully allow me to keep many weeks worth of snapshots of my home directories on the **ZFS** drive. The operating system's HDD where the *home* directories reside is **ext4** if that makes any difference. I would also like to have native **ZFS** support in my Ubuntu, not **FUSE**.

How should I go about achieving that in Ubuntu, using the command line? (not the whole backing-up thing, just the formatting).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your USB disk is /dev/sdb and will be used exclusively with ZFS:

```
zpool create pool sdb
zfs create pool/backup
```

Use /pool/backup as your rsync destination directory.

Create snapshots with:

```
zfs snapshot pool/backup@$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
```

Comment: should'nt I format the drive as ZFS first? 'sudo zpool create pool sdb' gives me "invalid vdev specification use '-f' to override the following errors: /dev/sdb is part of potentially active pool 'pool'". And when I try 'sudo zpool create -f pool sdb' I get "cannot open '/dev/sdb': Device or resource busy"

Comment: No, there is no such thing as ZFS formatting (assuming you mean creating a file system like with mk2efs).  Is /dev/sdb your USB disk ? Did you already create a ZFS pool on it ? Is there already a mounted file system on your USB disk ?

Comment: I created a ZFS pool with the "zpool create pool sdb" and "zfs create pool/backup" commands you provided. The USB disk was at /dev/sdb and was NTFS formatted with a mounted file system (which I however dismounted). Anyway, I'll accept your answer for now and will read up on ZFS pools a bit more ...

Comment: So the pools were already there when you got the error message. What says: `zpool list pool`, `zpool status pool` and `zpool history pool` ?